# Wordpress post-only ajax form gives jQuery error?

Tags: jquery, wordpress-theming, ajaxform

I have a wordpress site that has an ajax newsletter signup form. On the  homepage everything runs error free :-) On a blog post page, I get this error:

[Error] TypeError: e.indexOf is not a function. (In 'e.indexOf(" ")', 'e.indexOf' is undefined)
    (anonymous function) (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:31048)

[Error] TypeError: a.parent("a").size is not a function. (In 'a.parent("a").size()', 'a.parent("a").size' is undefined)
    (anonymous function) (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:31048)

The HTML:

```
<div class="newsletter-section">
        <div id="form-messages"></div>

    <div class="form-div d-flex justify-content-center">
        <form id="ajax-contact" method="POST" action="mailer.php">

            <input type="text" class="" id="email" name="email" required placeholder="Sign up for our newsletter">
            <div class="btn-center">
                <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>  
</div>
```

The code:

```
$(function() {

// Get the form.
var form = $('#ajax-contact');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(e) {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    e.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
        $(formMessages).addClass('success');

        // Set the message text.
        $(formMessages).text(response);

        // Clear the form.
        $('#email').val('');
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
        $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
        $(formMessages).addClass('error');

        // Set the message text.
        if (data.responseText !== '') {
            $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
        } else {
            $(formMessages).text('Oops! Er loopt iets fout. Je boeking is niet verzonden.');
        }
    });

});
```

});

Can anyone help me?

Thank you,
Fred

Comment: Could you post what `a` and `e` are and the html for those elements?  Basically the error is telling you that you're trying to call `indexOf()` on something that doesn't exist as of the time the call is made.

Comment: thank you @Bardicer I added the HTML and JS.

Comment: and added the code @Taplar !

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that I had to provide the absolute path to the php script in the form. It works faultless! Thanks for your attention.